# Can I upload the entire postgres DB on Github?

Tags: database, github, backups

Basically, here's the problem.

I work remotely for a company, and I need to have a local copy of the production database to play around with it and test my work on it before pushing the code. The prod DB is around 6GB, and so downloading it and then restoring it is time-intensive, to say the least. I want to commit the prod database to a repo, and create a cron job that automatically commits the daily updates to the repo. Since the data in a database is stored as files on the computer, I am assuming only the diffs will be committed and uploaded to Github. And then I want to check out locally and then pull the latest changes. That way, I will only be downloading the changes, not the whole prod replica, but will also keep updated.

Please note that I am not doing it to create a backup, i.e. I don't want or need the history. I just need a method to effectively only download the changes to my database locally instead of downloading the entire replica.

Comment: You should take this question to the company, not to stackoverflow. And for all companies I worked with, this action would get you fired,

Comment: That's not how relational databases or GitHub work.

Comment: Be aware that the data in that database may be security relevant. Therefore creating a copy (even in an theoraticly closed environment) may be a breach of the security guidelines of your company.

Comment: One approach of doing this is to set up a local test server using postgres replication option, and using a VPN tunnel to mirror the production database (assuming you got an official permission from the company to keep a full copy of the production data). An even better option would be if you can manage it to work in a way you don't need the whole production DB.

Comment: ... For example, I work here with a database system where, whenever we need some production data for reproducing an issue of a customer, they simply export the small portion of the data required for reproducing the problem in a local test environment. However, that requires your system having sane import and export functionality, which many database systems are lacking.

Comment: `Please note that I am not doing it to create a backup, i.e. I don't want or need the history` That's it. So, yes you can but no you should not. That's not for what an SCM is intended for. If you want to go down that way, moving the binaries to a remote folder within your LAN Network is going to be more "performant".

Comment: And community, downvotes are for bad questions, not for bad ideas.

Comment: It might interest. [PostgreSQL SR](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication)

Comment: The company should either define an entirely separate "test" database for the developers to use, or provide a system for testing in the cloud / otherwise remotely. Not on the local system.

Comment: If you aren't paying for GitHub, they'll probably ban you if you try to use it to store 6GB files that aren't part of your source code.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a proper use for Github, which is mainly a source code repository and not a general file store. Your assumptions about saving time by only storing the daily updates in git do not hold, database files are binary, and the changes cannot be expressed as textual diffs.

Forget about using a git repository and look at other ways of doing differential backups. [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257833/is-it-possible-to-take-full-and-differential-backup-in-postgresql-like-sql-serve) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529603/best-method-for-postgresql-incremental-backup) might be starting points.

Note that if you play around with your copy of the database you're most likely not able to merge later changes from the production database. You will have to restore the playground database to a copy of the production again. However, with WAL archiving that should be much faster (you're basically storing a full backup of the production database with the ability to restore to any point in time, and incremental update of this backup from the production server).

Note2: I have no practical experience doing this, just gathered that info using a search engine, so YMMV, but I'm very positive about not using GitHub or any other source code repository tool for this. And of course, what @mtj said: *Production database content does not belong on a publicly accessible service. Ever.* And what @JanRecker said, as well: *it probably doesn't belong on your computer either.*

Comment: "Production database content does not belong on a publicly accessible service." <- it's perfectly possible to have private repos on Github, just like lots of companies have their private source code on Github.

Comment: Of course it is possible. And no publicly available service has ever been compromised, and credentials have never been leaked. Right :-)

Comment: Also be aware that as much as I value software, the data in a database is often much more valuable and must be protected much more stringently. Think of password hashes and the legal requirements around protecting personal data.

Comment: @PhilipKendall even in the companies that do, source code likely sits in an entirely different classification to the prod database because the latter almost certainly contains PII and the former shouldn't. If the OP's assuming _"we put other things on GitHub so I can put this there"_, that can be a problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: my company would not even put mission-critical source code into a private GitHub repo - but the world is changing, and companies are relying more and more on Cloud services..

Comment: @DocBrown OK, I'm not saying everyone can or should use hosted VCS; my point was that _even if_ your company stored some things on GitHub, you can't extrapolate that to storing _anything_ on GitHub being OK.

Comment: "_Your assumptions about saving time by only storing the daily updates in git do not hold, database files are binary, and the changes cannot be expressed as textual diffs._" It's worse than that.  Git doesn't store textual diffs, even for source code files - it always stores the entire contents of every version of every file.

Comment: @RossPatterson: it is a little bit [more complicated](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/git-internals-how-works-kaushik-rangadurai).

Answer (score 2):

Others have discussed why uploading production data to the cloud is most likely a very bad idea.

What I did in a similar situation was to create a docker image with the database in question with the production data restored into it, so that instantiating the docker image instantly give access to the full data set (for a lenient interpretation of "instant")

I then put it on our internal Gitlab instance which includes a docker repository, so that it didn't leave our network at all.  Our dataset was around 1.5 Gb so this is most likely also feasible with your 6 Gb.

This worked very well for us.

Comment: Also - docker-compose is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to commit the prod database to a repo, and create a cron job that automatically commits the daily updates to the repo.
> ... the data in a database is stored as files on the computer, I am assuming only the diffs will be committed ...

```
Database != File(s)
```

The **only** time that the above is *not* true is after the database has been *cleanly* shut down.

The files used by just about *every* DBMS are in a proprietary, *binary* format, so working out what "changes" have been made "in there" is likely to be *very* difficult for *any* version control system.  You may well find that it just takes another copy of the whole thing, anyway!

Stop thinking about databases as *files*.
Perform database operations using database tools.

You don't say which DBMS you're using; you may find that a "dump" of the database could be *considerably* smaller than the database itself.

Comment: Well he did state "postgres" in the title...

Answer (score 0):

As all the others said, it's not how the Database to be used for test. Below are the points to be considered for production data replication.

1. You must have a test database.
2. You can have a daily job to replicate the data. Or you can do it manually for the required tables.
3. You must mask sensitive data and replace with placeholders.

Also, if you only need data to be read, you can create a user with only read privilege and you can use it for development.